# Angular child route not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to make routing and child routing work in a simple configuration, but I can not seem to make it work.

The routing:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BookingoverviewComponent } from './bookingoverview/bookingoverview.component';
import { BookingDetailsComponent } from './booking-details/booking-details.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'bookingoverview', component: BookingoverviewComponent, 
    children: [
        { path: 'bookingDetails', component: BookingDetailsComponent }
    ]},
    { path: 'bookingDetails', component: BookingDetailsComponent },  
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

And the links:

```
  <a routerLink="/bookingoverview">Bookingoverview</a> 
  <a [routerLink]="['/bookingoverview', 'bookingDetails']">Details-component</a> 
  <a [routerLink]="['bookingDetails']">Details-component</a>
```

localhost:4200/bookingoverview - works

localhost:4200/bookingDetails - works

localhost:4200/bookingoverview/bookingDetails - does not work! Shows only the bookingoverview.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ensure that you have two router outlets.

The App Component needs a `<router-outlet>` to display the main routes.

If a component has child routes, that component's template also needs a `<router-outlet>`. The child routes are then displayed within that router outlet.

If you want it in the same router outlet, don't use a child route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'bookingoverview', component: BookingoverviewComponent, 
    { path: 'bookingoverview/bookingDetails', component: BookingDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'bookingDetails', component: BookingDetailsComponent },  
];
```

Comment: Oh, of course. So if I want it in the same router-outlet I can use `{ path: 'bookingoverview/bookingDetails', component: BookingDetailsComponent }`?

Comment: If you want it in the same router outlet, don't make it a child route.

Comment: Exactly. Got it! Thanks :)

Comment: @DeborahK thanks master, I'm learning programming with your beauty courses. again another help from u.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in your bookingoverview component:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```